OpenAPI Enums getting mixed up during doc generation
I have an object with multiple properties and enums. In the generated documentation, the latter property also has the enums from the former property why is that?
Is there something wrong with my yaml?
User:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
      example: Susi
    status:
      type: string
      enum:
        - INACTIVE
        - ACTIVE
        - BANNED
        - BLOCKED
    paid:
      type: string
      format: date
      readOnly: true
[...]
    city:
      type: integer
      format: int32
      minimum: 0
      example: 63
    gender:
      type: string
      enum:
        - MALE
        - FEMALE
        - OTHER
      example: FEMALE
    profile:
      type: string
      example: I



seems ok.  which doc tool is processing this?

@Jeremy Fiel html2 openapi-generator-cli generate -i api.yml -g html2 -o doc/ you mean this is ok? How do I avoid that gender "inherit?" the enums from status
